# reactjs: Error in importing uikit.min.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, getuikit

I'm very new to react and not knowledgeable in using react natively so I use `create-react-app`.

I'm trying to use the **UIKit** as framework but I can't get it to work. Since UIKit's NPM module only supports its 2.x version, I'm trying to use its 3.x (from http://www.getuikit.com/). I am importing the JS file (`uikit.min.js`) in one of my components but it fails compiling.

I am including `import * as uikit from 'uikit.min.js';` in the file and this pops up when compiling:

```
./src/assets/js/uikit.min.js
  Line 3:  'define' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 3:  'define' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 4:  Unexpected use of 'location'    no-restricted-globals
  Line 4:  Unexpected use of 'location'    no-restricted-globals
  Line 5:  Unexpected use of 'location'    no-restricted-globals
  Line 5:  'DocumentTouch' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 5:  'MSGesture' is not defined      no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Maybe I'm doing it wrong but how can I import this for me to use UIkit v3?

Comment: You can probably include it in you HTML file as a  script dependency

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri tried that but I need to use UIkit's functions such as `UIkit.modal("...").toggle()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install UIkit with npm `npm install uikit`. Then:

```
import UIkit from 'uikit'
```

and remember that react works only with data attributes, citation from the docs:

> React will work with data-uk-* prefixes only.

Comment: Wasn't able to do this before because the npm module for uikit is not 3.x but sweet, there's an update 3 days ago. Thanks for this.

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers.